# Definition of In-order Traversal

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, inorder

In the `Tree` abstraction, that is currently being written(as code practice),

```
/************ tree.h *********************/

.....

/****************** Usage-start ************/
#if defined(LCRS)

  typedef struct LCRSTree Tree;

#elif defined(MULTI_WALK)

  typedef struct multiWalkTree Tree;

#elif defined(BINARY_TREE)

  typedef struct BinaryTree Tree;

#else

    #error "Invalid representation\n"

#endif

  .....

typedef void(*visitFunc)(void *);

Tree * newTree(void);
bool destroyTree(Tree *);
 ...
void preOrderTraversal(Tree*, visitFunc);
void postOrderTraversal(Tree *, visitFunc);
void breadthFirstTraversal(Tree *, visitFunc);

void inOrderTraversal(struct BinaryTree *, visitFunc);
.....

#endif  /* TREE_H */
/**************** Usage-end ******************/
```

---

`inOrderTraversal()` is declared as,

`void inOrderTraversal(struct BinaryTree *, visitFunc);`

which mean, `inOrderTraversal` accept binary tree but not N-ary tree(N>2), unlike pre-, post-, breadth first traversals.

Idea is inspired from this [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/44822/28929), where it says: *In-order traversal is a special case. It probably only makes sense for binary trees.*

Question:

Before final code change, Please confirm my understanding on usage of `inOrderTraversal()` in the above code.

Comment: @D.W. After reading your answer, linked in this query, In the apsect of traversal,   Am I going correctly with the code, ?

Comment: I think in order traversal can work with non-binary trees, but you need to define where the parent gets ordered with respect to its children for it to make sense.  For binary trees it'll generally be assumed that the parent fits between the two children -- but without such an assumption it wouldn't make sense for binary trees either.

Comment: think there is a decent question hiding behind this concept but that you havent asked it in a clear way. you seem to be wanting to know about in-order traversal of n-ary trees, answered that [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/67888/699)